# How to implement an external border-radius in pure CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a tab system similar to that of Google Chrome (see image).

[image]

Using `border-radius` CSS attribute, I can create the inner rounding (top-left and top-right), but I am unsure how to approach the outer rounding.

```css
.tabs {
    background-color: #E7EAED;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tab {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E7EAED;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tab.active {
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">Tab One</div>
    <div class="tab active">Tab Two</div>
    <div class="tab">Tab Three</div>
</div>
<div class="other">More Content here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.tabs {    
    margin-bottom: 15px;        
}

.tab {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #a7aAaD;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

.tab.active {
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.tab.active:after {
  background-color: #a7aAaD;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -10%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 120%;
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}

.tab.prev{
   border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.tab.next{
   border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab prev">Tab One</div>
    <div class="tab active">Tab Two</div>
    <div class="tab next">Tab Three</div>
</div>
<div class="other">More Content here</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if i get you correctly, you want to apply round edges to the tabs div? if yes, then apply border-radius to .tabs selector`.tabs{border-radius: 10px};`

Answer (score -1):

In your html page within the head tag

Then go to .css file

.tab {
border-radius: 10px
}

Note set to the px you want.

Comment: It's better if you copy the question's code snippet to your answer and correct it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code: .tabs { border-radius: 8px; } or u can just create another div housing your each of your tab which wouldn't be what you want.. the is answer is straight